# Make error in complex Makefile

Tags: makefile, typescript

I downloaded the [source code](https://git01.codeplex.com/typescript) from codeplex but 'make' errors out:

> [pc@localhost typescript]$ make
>   Makefile:123: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.

The offending line is apparently the 3rd line here:

```
$(BUILT_LOCAL)\typescript.js: $(COMPILER_SOURCES)
$(STRC_LKG) $(COMPILER_SOURCES) -out $@
    copy CopyrightNotice.txt+$@ $(BUILT_LOCAL)\temp.js /b
    copy $(BUILT_LOCAL)\temp.js $@ 
    del $(BUILT_LOCAL)\temp.js
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you using GNU Make?  The Makefile currently only works with NMake on Windows - we're working on Unix support now.

Comment: @JoePamer, Yes, I'm using GNU Make on Fedora/Linux. I'm very impressed with the intellisense on the typescript playground site. If you have any timeframe for the GNU Make support, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @JoePamer pointed out in the comments, it's an NMake file not a GNU Makefile. So this has **nothing** to do with "make"

If you want to build TypeScript with "make" on Linux. Check this out:

https://gist.github.com/3815802

`UPDATE:`
I've submitted a ticket about this issue. [typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/17](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/17)